# Why does Ctrl + C not kill Python running in terminal?

Tags: command-line, process, signal

I am trying to understand the reason why the whole Python process does not get killed when I press Ctrl + C inside and infinite loop or for that matter any Python function that I am running in terminal and only the loop/function is stopped?

Comment: CTRL+C historically has stopped only the current job-in-process, and not brought down the entire stack that job depends upon. Or it Copies whatever you've highlighted in a display. There is a long list of stuff that CTRL+C historically has never terminated: Display servers, daemons, interpreters, network connections, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the design of the Python interpreter and interactive session.

Ctrl + C sends a signal, [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT), to the Python process, which the Python interpreter handles by raising the [KeyboardInterrupt exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) in the currently-running scope.

If the interpreter is running in an interactive session (i.e. by running `python` or `python3` at the console), then the exception in the current function is printed and you return to the Python prompt. If the interpreter is running a script (e.g. by `python3 my_script.py`), then unless the KeyboardInterrupt is handled by the script, the whole program will stop when the exception is raised.

Comment: Can I do the same with a C program? If a function is running inside the main is it possible to just stop that function and return the control to main()?

Comment: I believe this would require you to use a signal handler. Programming questions like that are probably better on Stack Overflow rather than askubuntu - [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485028/signal-handling-in-c) might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out from the docs that you need to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` explicitly, even if you already have a catch for `Exception`:

`The exception inherits from BaseException so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches Exception and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting.`